# How to control the toggle of a button using a wrapper

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a Toggle Button and the specifications tells me that a group of Toggle Buttons should have the behavior to allow only single click([see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75TiT.png)) and multiple clicks([see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEqyN.png)).

Multiple click is just fine, since theres not much logic to implement, but the single click is pretty hard to me. The main idea of using the single click is that if i toggle a button and try to toggle another one, the previous should lost his state of `pressed` and the clicked one should have it. When `pressed` is true, the ToggleButton has a different CSS.

This is my toggle button component:

```
const ToggleButton = props => {
  const { onClick, value, ...other } = props;
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(true);
  const renderPressedButton = () => {
    setPressed(!pressed);
    if (onClick) {
      onClick();
    }
  };
  return (
    <StyledToggleButton
      className={!pressed ? 'pressed' : null}
      pressed={pressed}
      data-value={value}
      {...other}
      onClick={renderPressedButton}
    />
  );
};
```

and this is my wrapper(atm i'm only getting the class of what i'm clicking):

```
const onClickHandler = e => {
  const index = e.target.closest('.pressed');
  // console.log(index);
  // console.log('classe: ', e.target.className);
  if (index) {
    console.log('its pressed!');
  }
};

const ToggleButtonGroup = props => {
  const { ...other } = props;
  return <StyledToggleButtonGroup onClick={onClickHandler} {...other} />;
};
```

I think i should use Context API or maybe move my `renderPressedButton` logic to my wrapper. Anyone has an idea?

And this is how i plan to use the component:

```
<ToggleButtonGroup singleClick>
     <ToggleButton>One</ToggleButton>
     <ToggleButton>Two</ToggleButton>
</ToggleButtonGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lift the state up to `ToggleButtonGroup`. Maintain a list of toggled indices there and provide a boolean as prop to `ToggleButton` keeping it completely stateless. By this way, you will be able to control each `ToggleButton` individually from `ToggleButtonGroup` based on any click.

```
function ToggleButtonGroup({ singleClick, children }) {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState([]);

  const handleClick = event => {
    // event.target should have your clicked checbox reference
    const index = event.target.dataset.index;

    if (singleClick) {
      setChecked([index]);
    } else {
      if (checked.includes(index)) {
        setChecked(checked.filter(eachIndex => eachIndex !== index));
      } else {
        setChecked([...checked, index]);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          dataIndex: index,
          pressed: checked.includes(index)
        });
      })}
    </div>
  );
}



function ToggleButton({ dataIndex, pressed, ...rest }) {
  return <div data-index={dataIndex} className={!pressed ? 'pressed' : null} {...rest} />;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but how i'm going to be able to make the single click behavior?

Comment: If its single, make sure your indices state will have only one element. If its multiple, keep several elements.

Comment: Update with code where you just need one event handler at the top. Event from every checkbox will be bubbled up.

Comment: I dont see why you're returning an input on the ToggleButton. It was supposed to be only a div that changes the style(clicked or not clicked) according to onClick event.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a checkbox. I'll update the code but ideally the concept is to place a data index on the dom and listen to its event up the tree.

Comment: Thats pretty good. I can also use the components(ToggleGroup and ToggleButton) in different folders  and files or they have to be in the same file?

Comment: Upto you. That should not matter as long as you import and export the components correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the state at parent component

```
const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = useState(1);

<ToggleButtonGroup singleClick>
     <ToggleButton onClick={()=> setActiveButton(1)} isClicked={activeButton===1}>One</ToggleButton>
     <ToggleButton onClick={()=> setActiveButton(2)}  isClicked={activeButton===2}>Two</ToggleButton>
</ToggleButtonGroup>

// based on propsisClicked you can style <ToggleButton> however you want
```

Comment: Is there any way be able to not have onClick on each ToggleButton? To keep everything on ToggleButtonGroup.

Comment: sadly there isn't react wouldn't found out what did you click ,  it's the same component you just need to implement once :) and give it as a prop

Comment: I'm going to upvote but it's not the solution i'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: ['one','two'].map((buttonTitle,i) =>  <ToggleButton onClick={()=> setActiveButton(i)} isClicked={activeButton===i}>{buttonTitle}</ToggleButton>)

The closest you can get is using .map and implementing onClick only once